# What is the cause of this nullPointerException?

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, singleton

When I run my test harness I am getting a NullPointerException on the line:

```
if(flower.extractPollen(pol)){
```

which I am struggling to explain. In my test harness I am adding flowers to the instance of my garden and the flowers have pollen as far as I can tell from println's. In my test harness I am creating an instance of a garden, a queen bee (in an arraylist) in a hive and adding a rose and a daffodil (in an arraylist) to the garden. I then run another day on the hive and the garden which run another day on the flowers in the garden (adding pollen to them which I can tell is happening from a println) and creating more bees. When a worker bee is created it is supposed to get a flower from the instance of the garden and extract the pollen from it but I get a NullPointerException instead. Relevant code:

```
public class Worker{

    public Bee anotherDay(){
        for(int u = 0; u< 2; u++){
            Flower flower = Garden.getInstance().findFlower();
            for(int pol = 5; pol>0; pol--){
                if(flower.extractPollen(pol)){
                    if(pol>1){
                        hive.addRoyalJelly(1);
                        pol = pol - 2;
                        hive.addHoney(pol);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }//code omitted which returns the bee in this method and some other methods from the class
        } 
    }

public class Garden{
    private ArrayList<Flower> flowerbed = new ArrayList<Flower>();
    Hive hive = null;

    private static Garden instance;

    private Garden(){}

    public static Garden getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Garden();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void anotherDay(){
        int size = flowerbed.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Flower flower = flowerbed.get(i);
            System.out.println(flower);
            flower.grow();
        }
    } 

    public Flower getFlower(int fi){
        if(fi < flowerbed.size()){
            return flowerbed.get(fi);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Integer getRandomInteger(Integer max)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number;
        number = rand.nextInt(max) + 1;
        return new Integer(number);
    }   

    public Flower findFlower(){
        return getFlower(getRandomInteger(flowerbed.size()));
    }
}

public abstract class Flower{

    public boolean extractPollen(int po){
        if(po <= pollen){
            pollen= pollen - po;
            return true;
        }return false;
    }

    //subclasses are not abstract and in their grow methods pollen is added. Some other methods omitted
}
```

By using System.out.println() around my code I can see that the code which I use is adding a rose and  adoffodil to the instance of the garden and that by the time the Worker bee is created (on day 14) they have 28 and 42 pollen respectively. As the Worker is only trying to extract 5 I cannot see why I am getting this exception!! The stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Worker.anotherDay(Worker.java:21)
at Hive.anotherDay(Hive.java:105)
at TestBasicHive.testpart5(TestBasicHive.java:405)
at TestBasicHive.main(TestBasicHive.java:14)
```

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace of the null pointer exception?

Comment: adde the findFlower method code and about to add the stacktrace

Comment: `rand.nextInt(max) + 1` - why the `+ 1`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I thought I had a reason for that but when I removed it it got rid of the null pointer exception! Thank you- I would mark your comment as the correct answser if I could!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that your getFlower method is returning null because fi is greater than flowerbed.size();  Instead of returning null there, throw an exception and see what happens.  Throwing exceptions is generally preferred to returning null for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined a findFlower method?  I don't see any code for that.  That may help show where the null pointer is.

Your `rand.nextInt(max) + 1` should simply be `rand.nextInt(max)`.  By adding 1, it is possible that number equals the size of the Flower array, and in your `getFlower(fi)` method, you return `null` if **fi >=** the size of the Flower array.

Answer (score 1):

A comment would be more appropriate, but it is a reputation thing...

Your NullPointerException is because "flower" is null. I do not see the implementation of the findFlower method on your Garden class, but it probably is not finding the flower you are asking for...

...I see you added the implementation of the findFlower method...

Check your random integer generator and ensure that it is only returning values which are valid array indices. You should also change the code which calls findFlower to properly handle a null return since that is implemented as a possible result in the findFlower method.

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerExceptions are exceptions that occur when you try to use a reference that points to no location in memory (null) and by going through your below condition,

if(flower.extractPollen(pol)){

Here you are getting null pointer exception because flower variable is referenced with null and without doing null pointer check,you are trying to call extractPollen(pol) method.So do a null check to any object variable before you do some other stuff.